# How can I add a lat-long grid to a projected map?

Tags: r, dictionary, spatial, map-projections

EDIT: question really pertains to how one can add lat/long gridlines to a projected map. I changed title to match.

I have some layers in geographic coords. I want to plot them in LCC projection, but have a geographic (lat/long) grid. From `mapproj` I can use `map.grid()` to add a grid, with the limits set by the `lim` argument. It takes a vector or a range object:

> a vector of 4 numbers specifying limits: c(lon.low, lon.high, lat.low,
>   lat.high). lim can also be a list with a component named range, such
>   as the result of map, from which limits are taken.

I construct my map by clipping a large vector layer with a clipping polygon:

```
myPoly <- readOGR(dsn=".", layer="myPolygon")  # just a shapefile in geographic coords
library(raster)  # To convert an 'extent' object to a SpatialPolygons object
cp <- as(extent(146, 149, -39, -37.5), "SpatialPolygons")
proj4string(cp) <- CRS(proj4string(myPoly))  # copy from shapefile

# Transform and plot:
lcc <- CRS("+init=epsg:3111")
myPoly.proj <- spTransform(myPoly, lcc)
cp.proj <- spTransform(cp, lcc)  # transform the clip box
myPoly.proj.clip <- gIntersection(myPoly.proj, cp.proj, byid=TRUE)
plot(myPoly.proj.clip) 

# Then finally, add a lat/long grid:
map.grid(lim=as.vector(cp.proj@bbox), labels=TRUE)
```

That last line is not correct, as the @bbox returned is xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, but needs to be in xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax. There must be a simple solution to all this, but as usual I am lost in the vortex. I could manually create a limits vector, but really?

Comment: don't use @ - try lim = as.vector(t(bbox(cp.proj))), but I don't know if map.grid plays well with Spatial objects after plotting, for example how does map.grid know that you want longlat grid, and what projection your data is in?

Comment: @mdsumner - thanks. I have no idea if map.grid() knows what to do! Just trying to work out anything seems hard for me at the moment. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: @mdsumner - ?map.grid() says: `Draw a latitude/longitude grid on a projected map`, but I suppose it's talking about a map produced by the `map` function.

Comment: I think that's right. Pretty sure mapproj defaults to the unit sphere, so you're going to be pushing it uphill. See ?gridlines for working with sp. (This is a nightmare I know).

Comment: Ah-ha! `rgdal` has `llgridlines`, which does it I think! @mdsumner

Comment: OK, llgridlines seems good, but labelling is fixed. Starting to shiver and sweat here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: the OP points out `rgdal::llgridlines` which is a better solution.

You are using context from `sp/rgdal` which uses a different system to that of `mapproj/maps`.

Try this (untested):

```
library(rgdal)
gl <- gridlines(myPoly)
cp.gl <- spTransform(gl, lcc)
plot(cp.gl, add = TRUE)
```

See `?gridlines` for more on using this with labels. I find it works well as long as you stay away from circumpolar maps.